# How do you handle two beans with the same name in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have three `jar` and a `war`. `A`,`B`,`C` and `D(war)`, `A` and `B` depend on `C` and `D` depends on `A` and `B`.
There's an interface `X` in `C`.
There is an implementation class `Y` for `X` in `A` and an implementation class `Y` for `X` in `B`, both of them have the same `bean` name in `Spring`.

Like this :

```
package com.example.a
class Y implements X

package com.example.b
class Y implements X
```

My Question:

In `D`, I want to use `Spring` to get both `beans` at the same time. How to do it?

In 'C':

```
package com.example.c
public interface X {
    String getPath();
}
```

In 'A':

```
package com.example.a
@Component
public class Y implements X {
    public String getPath(){
        return "/User/name/application";
    }
}
```

In 'B':

```
package com.example.b
@Component
public class Y implements X {
    public String getPath(){
        return "/usr/local/bin";
    }
}
```

In 'D':

```
package com.example.d
public class Application{
    @Autowired
    private List<? extends X> xes;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(X x : xes){
            System.out.println(x.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

What do you do when `A` and `B` have exactly the same Y name ?

Comment: Are you using annotation or you are using config xml?

Comment: @SMA annotation

Comment: you are using xml?

Comment: One way would be, you could define your beans with name under configuration @Bean while you can inject them using qualifier annotation.

Comment: The classes have same name `Y` doesn't mean they are of same type. The type is different, why don't you autowire each type separately? Like:

`@Autowired
com.example.a Y;

@Autowired
com.example.b Y;`

Answer (score 4):

Though both bean have the same type (interface) , you can give them two difference names:

```
@Bean
public X beanYInPackageA(){
   return new com.example.a.Y();
}

@Bean
public X beanYInPackageB(){
   return new com.example.b.Y();
}
```

And use `@Qualifier` to further define which beans to inject by its bean name (wire by name) on top of `@Autowired` :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanYInPackageA")
private X beanYInPackageA;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanYInPackageB")
private X beanYInPackageB;
```

Comment: They have the same interface. but i can't control their names because their author is someone else.

Comment: I don't understand . Do you have total control in D , and from D , you want to use the beans which are provided by  A and B?

Comment: What their actual class names does not matter , you don't have to change their class name .What you need is to  to define them as a bean in D and give them a bean names like the codes I shown you above. Bean names is not the same as the Class name ,  bean names are totally controlled by you....

Comment: I see what you mean, but these two beans are automatically assembled from the `Jar` in which they reside

Comment: Are you sure Spring can assemble them ? I am very doubtful  based on what the codes you post out as it will most probably give you some error message saying that "the bean name are in conflict" .....

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to autowire a list of all the implementations of a given interface, spring provides this with the following code:

```
@Autowired
private List<X> list;
```

You can loop through the injected list.

For a complete example, you can go through [this](https://dzone.com/articles/load-all-implementors) link.

Comment: I want that: 

@Autowired
private List<X> xes;

Comment: I don't know the names of the implementation classes, I just want to get all the implementation classes and loop through their methods.

Comment: Could you give a pseudo code/example showing this? I did not get your question.